# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in stripe.confirmCardPayment in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // do all the fancy stripe stuff...
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);
    
    const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        }
    }).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
        // paymentIntent = payment confirmation
        if(error)
        {
          console.log('you have an error ',error)
        }
        else{
          db
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .collection('orders')
          .doc(paymentIntent.id)
          .set({
              basket: basket,
              amount: paymentIntent.amount,
              created: paymentIntent.created
          })

        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null)
        setProcessing(false)

        dispatch({
            type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
        })
        
        history.replace('/orders')
        }
        
    })

}
```

**My code stopped working before payload**
It is giving this error
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in stripe cardpayment
(anonymous function)
src/Payment.js:58
async handleSubmit
src/Payment.js:47

**My Payment.js **

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Payment.css';
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import CheckoutProduct from "./CheckoutProduct";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";
import { getBasketTotal } from "./reducer";
import axios from './axios';
import { db } from "./firebase";

function Payment() {
    const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
const history = useHistory();

const stripe = useStripe();
const elements = useElements();

const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    // generate the special stripe secret which allows us to charge a customer
    const getClientSecret = async () => {
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            // Stripe expects the total in a currencies subunits
            url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
        });
        setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
    }

    getClientSecret();
}, [basket])

console.log('THE SECRET IS >>>', clientSecret)
console.log('', user)

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // do all the fancy stripe stuff...
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);
    
    const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        }
    }).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
        // paymentIntent = payment confirmation
        if(error==true)
        {
          console.log('you have an error ',error)
        }
        else{
          db
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .collection('orders')
          .doc(paymentIntent.id)
          .set({
              basket: basket,
              amount: paymentIntent.amount,
              created: paymentIntent.created
          })

        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null)
        setProcessing(false)

        dispatch({
            type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
        })
        
        history.replace('/orders')
        }
        
    })

}

const handleChange = event => {
    // Listen for changes in the CardElement
    // and display any errors as the customer types their card details
    setDisabled(event.empty);
    setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
}

return (
    <div className='payment'>
        <div className='payment_container'>
            <h1>
                Checkout (
                    <Link to="/checkout">{basket?.length} items</Link>
                    )
            </h1>


            {/* Payment section - delivery address */}
            <div className='payment_section'>
                <div className='payment_title'>
                    <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
                </div>
                <div className='payment_address'>
                    <p>{user?.email}</p>
                    <p>123 React Lane</p>
                    <p>Los Angeles, CA</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* Payment section - Review Items */}
            <div className='payment_section'>
                <div className='payment_title'>
                    <h3>Review items and delivery</h3>
                </div>
                <div className='payment_items'>
                    {basket.map(item => (
                        <CheckoutProduct
                            id={item.id}
                            title={item.title}
                            image={item.image}
                            price={item.price}
                            rating={item.rating}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        

            {/* Payment section - Payment method */}
            <div className='payment_section'>
                <div className="payment_title">
                    <h3>Payment Method</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="payment_details">
                        {/* Stripe magic will go */}

                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <CardElement onChange={handleChange}/>

                            <div className='payment_priceContainer'>
                                <CurrencyFormat
                                    renderText={(value) => (
                                        <h3>Order Total: {value}</h3>
                                    )}
                                    decimalScale={2}
                                    value={getBasketTotal(basket)}
                                    displayType={"text"}
                                    thousandSeparator={true}
                                    prefix={"$"}
                                />
                                <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}>
                                    <span>{processing ? <p>Processing</p> : "Buy Now"}</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                              {/* Errors */}
                            {error && <div>{error}</div>}
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

    export default Payment
```

**In my code 58th line is db and 47 is payload**
(anonymous function)
src/Payment.js:58
async handleSubmit
src/Payment.js:47

Answer (score 1):

The error is (message: "As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a description. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports) in my case....
and I spend more days to find out it... finally done

so the confirmCardPayment method does not return a Payment Intent../

And solution is change currency from 'USD' to other currency like 'INR' in (functions/index.js)

```
 amount : total, 
    currency : 'INR'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing together two approaches to providing the `CardElement` for `card` in `confirmCardPayment`. If you already have a variable for `CardElement` you can use that directly:

```
const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
  payment_method: {
    card: CardElement
  }
})
```

If you need to look it up with [`getElement`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/get_element#elements_get_element-type) then the correct use is to provide the string `'card'`:

```
elements.getElement('card')
```

Ultimately I suspect that `confirmCardPayment` is returning an error and you're trying to accessing `id` on `paymentIntent` before confirm it has a value. You should verify success (ie, inspect the value or check the [`error`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment)) before accessing properties.